# How to integrate Spring AOP with Grails 3

Tags: spring, grails, aop, spring-aop, grails-3.3

I'm stuck trying to integrate spring aop for loggin in grails 3. I'm able to use logging inside the service class or controllers using log.info and I want to use it inside an aspect class.

This is my application.yml where I set the configuration for spring aop.

```
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
             check-template-location: false
    bean:
        packages: "com.escom.controlVolumetrico.aop"
    aop:
        proxy-target-class: true
```

Comment: Can you please format your yml?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice the yml was unformatted, but it's done.